“Error in initializePtr() : function 'cholmod_factor_ldetA' not provided by package 'Matrix'” when applying lmer function
I keep on receiving an error when I use the lmer() function:
Error in initializePtr() : function 'cholmod_factor_ldetA' not
 provided by package 'Matrix'

I have tried multiple times based recommendations from the previous post "Error in initializePtr() : function 'cholmod_factor_ldetA' not provided by package 'Matrix'" when using lmer function in R
I have tried:
install.packages("lme4", type = "source") library(lme4)

oo <- options(repos = "https://cran.r-project.org/") 
utils::install.packages("Matrix") 
utils::install.packages("lme4") 
options(oo)

install.packages("lme4", type = "source") 
library(lme4)

oo <- options(repos = "https://cran.r-project.org/") 
install.packages("Matrix", type="binary") 
install.packages("lme4", type="binary")
options(oo) 

install.packages("lme4", type = "source") 
library(lme4)

remove.packages("Matrix")
remove.packages("lme4") 

install.packages("lme4", type = "source")

library(lme4)

However, I keep on receiving the error when I use lmer().

Which version of R are you on?

Can you please post the exact, full output you are getting from each of these steps (in a text format, not as an image/screenshot)? Otherwise we will be reduced to frustrating guessing. The results of sessionInfo() from a clean R session would also be useful.
